# Difference between overlap and intersect methods in Pyranges

Tags: python, bioinformatics, pyranges

Pyranges class from similarly named package has two methods with slightly different functionality:
[intersect](https://pyranges.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoapi/pyranges/pyranges/index.html#pyranges.pyranges.PyRanges.intersect) and
[overlap](https://pyranges.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoapi/pyranges/pyranges/index.html#pyranges.pyranges.PyRanges.overlap).
Intersect method description is quite similar to overlap's one: `Return overlapping subintervals.` vs `Return overlapping intervals.`
I can't quite glimpse the difference between those two (Yeah, I noticed that `sub` prefix).

Is `overlap` intended to reveal full intervals that do overlap at least at one position?

Comment: Thanks for asking; it is a good question. I should have perhaps made the docstring for intersect: `Return intersections of overlapping query and subject intervals`, but the main docstrings are always so terse it is hard to understand them. Best to look at the examples too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup:

```
>>> import pyranges as pr
>>> gr = pr.from_dict({"Chromosome": ["chr1"] * 3, "Start": [1, 4, 10],
...                    "End": [3, 9, 11], "ID": ["a", "b", "c"]})
>>> gr
+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|   Chromosome |     Start |       End | ID         |
|   (category) |   (int32) |   (int32) | (object)   |
|--------------+-----------+-----------+------------|
|         chr1 |         1 |         3 | a          |
|         chr1 |         4 |         9 | b          |
|         chr1 |        10 |        11 | c          |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
Unstranded PyRanges object has 3 rows and 4 columns from 1 chromosomes.
For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.
>>> gr2 = pr.from_dict({"Chromosome": ["chr1"] * 3, "Start": [2, 2, 9], "End": [3, 9, 10]})
>>> gr2
+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| Chromosome   |     Start |       End |
| (category)   |   (int32) |   (int32) |
|--------------+-----------+-----------|
| chr1         |         2 |         3 |
| chr1         |         2 |         9 |
| chr1         |         9 |        10 |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+
Unstranded PyRanges object has 3 rows and 3 columns from 1 chromosomes.
For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.
```

With `overlap`, you get back the intervals in self that overlapped those in other. If an interval overlapped more than once, it is still only returned once (by default):

```
>>> gr.overlap(gr2)
+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| Chromosome   |     Start |       End | ID         |
| (category)   |   (int32) |   (int32) | (object)   |
|--------------+-----------+-----------+------------|
| chr1         |         1 |         3 | a          |
| chr1         |         4 |         9 | b          |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
Unstranded PyRanges object has 2 rows and 4 columns from 1 chromosomes.
For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.
```

With `intersect` the returned intervals are the intersection of the overlapping intervals in self and other. All overlaps are returned by default:

```
>>> gr.intersect(gr2)
+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| Chromosome   |     Start |       End | ID         |
| (category)   |   (int32) |   (int32) | (object)   |
|--------------+-----------+-----------+------------|
| chr1         |         2 |         3 | a          |
| chr1         |         2 |         3 | a          |
| chr1         |         4 |         9 | b          |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
Unstranded PyRanges object has 3 rows and 4 columns from 1 chromosomes.
For printing, the PyRanges was sorted on Chromosome.
```

See the docs for more info:

- [intersect](https://pyranges.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoapi/pyranges/pyranges/index.html#pyranges.pyranges.PyRanges.intersect)
- [overlap](https://pyranges.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoapi/pyranges/pyranges/index.html#pyranges.pyranges.PyRanges.overlap)